# Calling multiple services in parallel

Tags: wcf

I need to call two WCF services at a time. Both these services return similar output (Y/N). If either service returns Y, then I will not wait for the other. But if first service returns N, then I will wait for the second response.

Comment: Strange requirements!

Comment: What did you try? What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Launch 2 different threads if one is over, kill the other.